# Azure DevOps container jobs: Publish step (sometimes) run in host even though it's a container job

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Does anybody know how to guarantee that a step runs inside the container on a container job in Azure DevOps?

I setup a container job, as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops

First I specify the container, e.g.

```yaml
resources:
  containers:
    - container: docker_build
      image: my_docker_image:latest
      endpoint: MyEndpoint
```

Later I specify a job as running in a container

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: my_first_job
    timeoutInMinutes: 10
    pool:
      name: my-agent-pool

    container: docker_build
```

Now I added a publish step for an artifact in my workspace:

```yaml
    - publish: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my_artifact.tar.gz'
      artifact: some_artifact
      displayName: Some build artifact
```

Now the pipeline errors out with `/agent/_work/1/my_artifact.tar.gz` not existing. However I just created that file in the previous step. Why do I think Azure is running this on the host? Because the workspace should be called `/__w/1/` when called from within the container job.

Adding the container as target doesn't help.

```yaml
    - publish: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/my_artifact.tar.gz'
      target:
        container: docker_build
      artifact: some_artifact
      displayName: Some build artifact
```

Now the most infuriating thing: this works **sometimes**, because sometimes AzureDevOps decides to run this in the container I guess? EDIT: I'm actually not sure it ever runs in the container. Since I see that the times it works Pipeline.Workspace is mounted as a whole to the container. In the times it fails, only parts of Pipeline.Workspace are mounted.

Is there any way to guarantee the target of where the steps are executed or are Azure Container Jobs just completely broken?

Answer (score 0):

**Usually when we refer container instance at the stage level, all the tasks under this stage will run inside the container only.**

I have tried to repro this in my environment and got the results as expected.
To repro, I have created a sample yaml pipeline as below.

[image]

```
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
    - container: cont01
      image: ubuntu:20.04

jobs:
- job: job1
  displayName: job1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - script: echo $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    displayName: 'Run script on container'
    target:
      container: cont01
  - script: echo $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    displayName: 'Run script on host machine'

    
- job: job2
  displayName: job2
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  container: cont01

  steps:
  - script: echo $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    displayName: 'Run script on container'
  - script: printenv
    displayName: 'print env'
```

In the above code, I have used variable **$(Pipeline.Workspace)** to know where the task is running.

If the task runs on container instance, value of **$(Pipeline.Workspace)** will be **/__w/1**

If the task runs on host machine, value of **$(Pipeline.Workspace)** will be **/home/vsts/work/1**

Below is the output of the task **Run script on container (where the container instance is referred at task level)** in **job1.**

[image]

Below is the output of the task **Run script on host machine** in **job1.**

[image]

Below is the output of the task **Run script on container (where the container instance is referred at job level** in **job2.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried both as I posted, and it always replaces `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` with `/agent/_work/x/`, so I know it's running on the host. I found that sometimes the container gets a mount of the workspace, sometimes only subfolders are mounted. After adding `-v /agent/_work:/__w` to my options it seems to "work". I'm saying "work" since I can only download to the mounted workspace or publish from there.